# WPF - TwoWay binding to Image

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a twoway bind that works on one page. I will show how the data gets there by including the declaration code (not complete).

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:myViewModel x:Key="myList" />
</Page.Resources>

<ListView x:Name="mylvw" 
          DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=myList}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myItems}"

<Image DataContext ="{Binding SelectedItem, 
                      ElementName=lvw, 
                      Mode=TwoWay}"
       Source="{Binding Path=myImage}" />
```

So I click on the item in the listview and it populates the image with stored image and I am able to change the image using the TwoWay bind.

My problem page has a different setup. I want to show the selected listview item (ViewModel) in a new window. I am calling the window from a Command in the ViewModel and setting the Datacontext for the Window there:

```
class myViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public ICommand OpenDetailsCommand
        {
            get { return new RelayCommand(OpenDetailsWindow); }
        }

    public void OpenDetailsWindow()
        {
            myWindow w = new myWindow();
            w.DataContext = this;
            w.Show();
        }
```

So I have no resource in this window i.e. Window.Resource

My image is the following:

```
<Image x:Name="myImage" 
       Source="{Binding Path=myImage}"/>
```

This shows the image but I am unable to use the binding to change the image on edit.
If I try:

```
<Image x:Name="myImg" 
       Source="{Binding Path=myImage, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

The binding does not work at all ... no image displayed.
So i tired to specify the TwoWay in the Datacontext in the following way:

```
<Image x:Name="myImg"
       DataContext="{Binding myImage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
       AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, TwoWay}"
       Source="{Binding Path=myImage}"/>
```

I tried this as a way of replicating the one that works. This also does not bind at all i.e. no image displayed.

So I have 3 questions

1. How can I get the Image to bind to the windows datacontext in a TwoWay mode.
2. Am I doing this all wrong from the start by setting the Datacontext in the
   ViewModel?
3. Is there a better way to pass ViewModels from window/page to window/page?

Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the use `TwoWay` mode for a large `Image` in this case, may be a problem with the performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve this by changing the Image binding on the problem page and keep my original set up.

```
<Image
    DataContext="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=myPage, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Source="{Binding Path=myModel.myImage}" />
```

This gives me the TwoWay binding I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is in view model you dont have any property `myImage` to which you have bound your `Image` in new window. So in order to make binding work create a property like `SelectedItem` of type of item in `itemslist` on your `viewmodel` and bind the `listview` to it like:

```
<ListView x:Name="mylvw" 
          DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=myList}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=myItems}"
SelectedItem = "{Binding SelectedItem}"
```

Now since you have set the `DataContext` of your new window to the present viewmodel so you can bind the `Image` on your new window as

```
<Image x:Name="myImage" 
       Source="{Binding Path=SelectedItem.myImage}"/>
```